# Function driver.switchTo.frame() not working in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I try to switch to frame on the webpage using Webdriver in Selenium in Python, it shows me the error. Please find my code below:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame");
```

> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switchTo'

Comment: Swithcto(). is not a method in python

Comment: @iamsankalp89: It is unlikely to be a method anywhere.

Answer (score 18):

That's because you're using the Java method. In Python you should use

```
driver.switch_to.frame("frame_name")
```

Answer (score 5):

switchTo() is not a Python method. You should try

```
browser.switch_to.frame("frame");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")
```

For more information please go through this link:

**http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html**

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be an older question, but encountered this myself today, so wanted to share the built-in methods for this when using python. A good IDE helps:

[image: Switch To Options in Python]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50899562/edit) (it covers answers as well).