# 'Page' object has no attribute 'switch_to'

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I am having a problem with iframe. I can't find a way to enter the iframe and I get error:

> `AttributeError: 'ChangeBookingPage' object has no attribute 'switch_to'`

Full Traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/dusandev/Downloads/fishingbooker-web-tests/orqa/commands/worker.py",
> line 193, in run_test
> prepared_test()   File "/Users/dusandev/Downloads/fishingbooker-web-tests/utils/misc.py",
> line 315, in result
> return func(driver, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/dusandev/Downloads/fishingbooker-web-tests/fbtests/teams/marketplace/change_booking/test_change_booking_positive.py",
> line 579, in
> test_accepted_customer_change_persons_positive_difference_new_card_customer_withdraw
> pages.change_booking.enter_new_credit_card()   File "/Users/dusandev/Downloads/fishingbooker-web-tests/fbtests/pages/change_booking.py",
> line 147, in enter_new_credit_card
> self.credit_card_field_iframe.switch_to_iframe()   File "/Users/dusandev/Downloads/fishingbooker-web-tests/orqa/framework/elements/element.py",
> line 35, in switch_to_iframe
> self.page.switch_to.frame(self.locator) AttributeError: 'ChangeBookingPage' object has no attribute 'switch_to'

Here is the code:

In my fbdriver py file

```
 def switch_to_iframe(self, locator):
    self.find_element_by_locator(locator)
    self.switch_to.frame(locator)
```

In my element py file

```
 def switch_to_iframe(self):
    self.page.switch_to.frame(self.locator)
```

In my ChangeBookingPage py file

```
 credit_card_field_iframe = Element('id=braintree-hosted-field-number')


 def enter_new_credit_card(self):
    self.credit_card_field_iframe.switch_to_iframe()
```

EDIT: Element class

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, page=None):
        self.locator = locator
        self.page = page

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return self.__class__(self.locator, obj)

    def text(self):
        return self.page.get_element_text(self.locator)

    def is_element_available(self):
        return self.page.is_element_available(self.locator)

    def attribute_text(self, attribute):
        return self.page.get_element_attribute(self.locator, attribute)

    def click(self):
        self.page.click(self.locator)

    def send_keys(self, keys):
        self.page.send_keys(self.locator, keys)

    def switch_to_iframe(self):
        self.page.switch_to.frame(self.locator)
```

Comment: That's because you're using Java method. In Python you should use
`driver.switch_to.frame("frame_name")` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831217/function-driver-switchto-frame-not-working-in-selenium)

Comment: Hi Hamidreza, I think I am using correct Python method, check my fbdriver file: its switch_to.frame

Comment: What is `Element` ?

Comment: @cruisepandey i have updated question for you to check Element examples

Comment: Here `credit_card_field_iframe = Element('id=braintree-hosted-field-number')` you are not passing a page to constructor which is `None` by default. How do you then call `self.page.switch_to.frame(self.locator)` if `self.page` is `None`?